# Is there a way to monitor the status of SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I work as a system administrator in a Datacentre and as part of my daily routine work, I mostly need to establish a SSH tunnel to access certain critical services to work on. But sometimes the tunnel dies due to network drop. I would like to check whether is there a way to have some SSH tunnel monitor program to check the live status of the tunnel.

For example:

- Green indication when the connection is active and red indication when the tunnel is not active and to which server the tunnel has got established etc..

Comment: The only reliable way I've found is to test it periodically,`tcping` would be one way to do such tests..   have you tried autossh?

Comment: https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/ & http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/. Using `autossh` is exactly what I do as well.

Comment: Shows how to make it into a systemd - https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568.

Comment: Another approach is shown here using `lsof` - https://superuser.com/questions/248389/list-open-ssh-tunnels.

Comment: It depends how the tunnel is started but if one ssh connection is used only for that, if the tunnel closes then it means ssh is stopped. So you just need to check if ssh is running or not.